# My iPod 5th Gen won't turn on

Tags: battery, ipod-touch, charging

I have an iPod Touch 5th gen and I use a cheap £1 charger to charge it up.
Recently my iPod ran out of battery so I plugged it in using the charger and the iPod was completely unresponsive.
I tried everything including rebooting it, after that I took it to a local repair shop and he 'repaired' it for me but again my iPod ran out of charge and it won't come on again.
What do I do?

P.S : I have been using cheap chargers for a while now so it's only a recent problem, also if I bought an official Apple charger would it solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried charging it with a different charger or using a computer? Maybe the charger is just broken?

Comment: i have tried using a computer and that doesn't work, the charger i use will charge my Ipod when i have charge in my Ipod but when it runs out of battery it won't work.

Comment: Ask the shop what they did, since they seem to know the issue

Answer (score 1):

hold the power button and home button at the same time until the white apple logo appears be patient whenever this happens its a minor glitch in the iOS